# sgen doesn't serialize system.xml.dll

Tags: .net, wcf, dll, service, sgen

I'm working on a WCF service project. I need System.XML.XmlSerializers.dll, so I ran sgen on system.XML.dll on command-line, but I got this error:

> Error: Cannot deserialize type 'System.Xml.XmlWriterSettings' because
>   it contains property 'OutputMethod' which has no public setter.

What should I do now?

If anyone can help, I would appreciate it.
Thank you in advance.
This is the command i use:

```
sgen.exe system.XML.dll
```

What is the right command to use or before using sgen should I do something?

Comment: The real question is: why do your data contracts contain a member from System.Xml?

Comment: it's not related to data contracts.i use a third party dll that one of its methods needs system.xml.xmlserializers.dll